# Type hint of AsyncContextManager in PyCharm

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, python-asyncio, python-typing

I'm using Pycharm Professional 2022.1.
I have an async method I use to manage the session with my database in asynchronous environments

```
@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def begin_transaction(self) -> AsyncIterator[Session]:
    _session: Optional[Session] = None
    try:
        await self.session_lock.acquire()
        _session: Session = Session()
        yield _session
    finally:
        if _session is not None:
            _session.commit()
            _session.close()

        if self.session_lock.locked():
            self.session_lock.release()
```

But, when I use this method in an async statement, Pycharm doesn't recognize the type :

[image]

To use PyCharm auto-completion, I have to manually specify the type of the Session :

[image]

So, do you have any trick to type hint the output variable of a with statement on PyCharm without having to manually specify it ?

Comment: Simple answer is no, you'll have to type hint the variable outside the scope for it to autocomplete inside the scope. I can't fully explain why the linter doesn't resolve the type in the first case but the need to type hint ahead of the context manager's scope is common, it also happens with several constructs if using mypy, etc... Doing so isn't a mistake and there's no rule against correctly type hinting your variables when one of the tools you're using (like PyCharm's autocomplete in this case) needs it.

Comment: I believe the issue is the decorator. A decorator can alter a function’s return value so type checkers need to look at the decorator’s return type, not the function’s.

Comment: It's pretty strange, because `mypy` doesn't have plugin for that and inferes type correctly for [this code](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=3f91aa35b2d881b65b547fd18c0a8743). It might be version issue, because type is properly defined in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/contextlib.pyi#L131=) now. You can try using custom typeshed directory (I've seen it's possible in pycharm, but I'm fan of another editor, can't help with this more).

Comment: This is a known issue with PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36444 (issue is with contextmanager, same thing as asyncontextmanager).